# Pass dropdown value to code behind static method

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I am trying to use a language selection value in my code behind autocomplete method. I tried using a hidden_field but that does not work. Also ajax did not work for me.

This is my html dropdown menu:

```
<!-- Language Picker-->
    <div class="row" hidden="hidden">
            <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="lang_sel" style="width: 200px; position: relative; left: 19px;"  data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <option value="no_sel">Please select a language</option>             
                <option value="German">German</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
            </select>
    </div>
```

And this is my method in code behind:

```
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptMethod()]
        [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
        public static List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText, int count)
        {
            string sys_lang = here the language should be transmitted;
            string table = null;
            //Database/Table Selection
            if (sys_lang == "German")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Deutsch");
                table = "translation.dbo.de_translation";
            }
            if (sys_lang == "Spanish")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Spanisch");
                table = "translation.dbo.sp_translation";
            }
            if (sys_lang == "French")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Französich");
                table = "translation.dbo.fr_translation";
            }
            if (sys_lang == "no_sel")
            {
                //MessageBox.Show("Keine Sprache gefunden");
                table = null;
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Sprache" + "=" + sys_lang);


            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
            {
                con.ConnectionString = connection;

                using (SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand())
                {
                    com.CommandText = "SELECT Source FROM" + " " + table + " " + "WHERE Source like @Search + '%'";

                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Search", prefixText);
                    com.Connection = con;
                    con.Open();
                    List<string> suggestions = new List<string>();
                    using (SqlDataReader sdr = com.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (sdr.Read())
                        {
                            suggestions.Add(sdr["Source"].ToString());
                        }
                    }
                    con.Close();
                    return suggestions;
                }
            }
        }
```

I just want to do something like this:

```
string sys_lang = hidden_field.Value;
```

I hope someone has an idea.

---

Update

---

This is my hidden field:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="hidden_language" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"> </asp:HiddenField >
```

I initialized this variable:

```
public string language = null;
```

I tried to change the language with the following method:

```
public void Lang_Change(string lang)
        {
            language = lang;
        }
```

And I tried it with this ajax function:

```
$.ajax({  
                    type: "POST",  
                    url: "/default.aspx/Lang_Change",  
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",  
                    data: '{"lang":"' + $("#hidden_language").val() + '"}',  
                    dataType: "html",  
                    success: function ()
                    {  
                        alert("SUCCESS");  
                    },  
                    error: function ()
                    {  
                        alert("FAIL");
                    }  
                });
```

But it fails every time. The name of the page is default.aspx. I don't know if the path is wrong or something.

Comment: since you're trying to call a WebMethod, you need to use AJAX, that's really what it's designed for. So please show your ajax code which you tried, and explain what is going wrong. It should be fairly straightforward to get the selected value from the dropdown and send it to the server. `sys_lang` will need to be one of the input parameters to your webmethod.

Comment: Check my answer below please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I'll post just the "pass the parameter to codebehind" solution. From [Mudassar Ahmed Khan's website](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Calling-ASPNet-WebMethod-using-jQuery-AJAX.aspx) (my favorite) I recreated the example according to your requirement, you'll have to recraft it for database queries:

**AjaxTest.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="AjaxTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="AjaxTest" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <!-- Language Picker-->
            <select class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" id="lang_sel" style="width: 200px; position: relative; left: 19px;" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                <option value="no_sel">Please select a language</option>
                <option value="German">German</option>
                <option value="French">French</option>
                <option value="Spanish">Spanish</option>
            </select>
            <br /> <br />
            <input id="btnSetLanguage" type="button" value="Set language" onclick="SetLanguage()" />
        </div>
    </form>

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script type = "text/javascript">
        function SetLanguage() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "AjaxTest.aspx/Lang_Change",
                data: '{language:"' + $("#lang_sel option:selected").text() + '" }',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: OnSuccess,
            failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.d);
            }
            });
        }
        function OnSuccess(response) {
            alert(response.d);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

**AjaxTest.cs (code behind)**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class AjaxTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Lang_Change(string language)
    {
        return "Language selected: " + language;
    }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: I altered your solution a little bit but in total it worked. Thank you very much