# Asp.net textbox shows text and value differently

Tags: asp.net

I am populating the value of a text box using javascript document getElementById.

I am able to see the text change in UI. However in code behind it shows a different value. I did inspect element on the input and saw the value and text are showing differently. How is this possible.

This is what I see on inspect element Value = '19 Bradston Street (South Bay)' but the UI shows ' 35-49 East Santa Clara Street' :-

```
<input name="ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$CtlPropertySales$txtBuildingName" type="text" value=" 19 Bradston Street (South Bay)" id="ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CtlPropertySales_txtBuildingName" tabindex="95" style="font-family:tahoma,verdana;font-size:11px;font-weight:normal;height:16px;width:150px;">
```

This is the Javascript code that is setting the value:-

```
document.getElementById('<%=CtlPropertySales.FindControl("txtBuildingName").ClientID%>').value = params[1]
```

Can any one tell me how this is possible and how I can solve this.

Comment: The value attribute will show the value set when the control was rendered by the server. I won't change when you set the `value` property.

Comment: @hardkoded - what is the solution ? These are text boxes in a user control.

Comment: So, what's your problem? You changes are being lost on postback? how are you posting those values? are those input disabled or read only?

Comment: You could send the client-side value to code behind via `ajax` and `WebMethod`. The following answer could give you a clue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50843635/1821637

Comment: Just fyi, I updated my original answer if you want to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you might not be getting the ID properly. You're looking for

```
<%=CtlPropertySales.FindControl("txtBuildingName").ClientID%>
```

but what is the ID for `CtlPropertySales`? Try getting the ClientID of `CtlPropertySales` first, then get the ClientID of `txtBuildingName`.

Or just

```
document.getElementById('<%=ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_CtlPropertySales_txtBuildingName.ClientID%>').value= params[1]
```

---

You might consider add this to your web.config:

```
<system.web>
    <pages clientIDMode="Static">
</system.web>
```

With `clientIDMode="Static"`, IDs will retain their original name and you will not need to use `ctl00` or `ClientID` any more. That should help with setting values, but it will affect all the IDs in the app/site and you'll have to update scripts.

Comment: Updated with more info and better answer.